# Reopen or repost?

Tags: discussion, reposting

Which choice is better: re-posting a closed challenge with 4 downvotes, or reopen the closed challenge?

The only problem seen in [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25982/remove-duplicates-from-one-list) challenge (at least by me) is that the spec is too unclear. If this challenge is not a duplicate, it is a valid challenge on CGCC.

However, reposting the same challenge also seems to be a valid option (at the risk of VTC as a duplicate); [it is easier post a new question instead of editing.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52944719#52944719) Reposting is easier to find out the flaws, although I suspect editing over the same challenge content will achive the same result.

Comment: Surely you should use the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Post a new question

While we do try to avoid reposting when unnecessary, it has been done on this site a number of times. In this case, the original question is almost 5 years old, has a net score of -4, and, before the recent edits, was a poor, underspecified challenge. By posting an updated version to the Sandbox, you avoid jumping the shark with editing the original, and you can start with a "fresh slate", so to say: namely, the question doesn't already have 5 downvotes.

I would recommend asking Quintec for their permission to repost, but so long as they have  no issue with it, and the question is up to our current standards, I see no problem with redoing it.

Comment: Should we define a minimum age for reposting? Like say 1+ years?

Comment: @frank I don’t think that‘s necessary. Reposting happens so rarely it’s fine to go case by case, rather than blanket rules.